Why can't I load the dataset in this data visualization based JavaScript program?
I am starting starting to dive deeper into programming and have started with d3 library. I wanted to run a program that will create a scatterplot and parallel line graphs using a penguin dataset I have but the first line of code itself is showing errors and for the life of me I can not debug the program.
JavaScript file:
//this is where I am getting my syntax error, I can not use a module statement outside of a module

import \* as d3 from d3;

// loading the dataset
const dataset = await d3.csv("data/penguins.csv", d3.autoType);

const numerics = \['bill_length_mm', 'bill_depth_mm', 'body_mass_g'\];
const categorical = "species";

const color_scale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
.domain(\['Adelie', 'Chinstrap', 'Gentoo'\])
.range(\['#1f77b4', '#ff7f0e', '#2ca02c'\]);

// Parent HTML element that contains the labels and the plots
const parent = d3.select("div#visualization");

// Sizes of the plots
const width = 800;
const height = 800;
const labelHeight = 25;

createLegend();
createScatterPlotMatrix(width, height);
createHorizontalParallelCoordinates(width, height / 2);

function createLegend() {
const margin = { top: 5, left: 20, bottom: 5, right: 10 };

    // Use 'species' attribute for the labels
    const labels = ['Adelie', 'Chinstrap', 'Gentoo'];
    
    const svg = parent.append("svg")
        .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, labelHeight]);
    
    const labelPositions = d3.scaleBand().domain(labels).range([margin.left, width - margin.right]);
    
    const radius = (labelHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom)/2;
    
    const y_circle = margin.top + radius;
    const y_label = labelHeight - margin.bottom*1.3;
    
    // Add all circles for the legend
    // Use 'color_scale' function for the colors
    svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(labels)
    .join("circle")
    .attr("cx", d => labelPositions(d))
    .attr("cy", y_circle)
    .attr("r", radius)
    .attr("fill", d => color_scale(d));  // Add color to the legend
    
    // Add all text to the legend
    svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(labels)
    .join("text")
    .attr("x", d => labelPositions(d) + 2*radius)
    .attr("y", y_label)
    .text(d => d)
    .style("font-size", 2*radius);

}

/\*\*

* Create Scatter Plot Matrix with the given width and height. The contents of each cell

* in this matrix is defined by the scatterPlot() function.

* 

* @param {integer} width

* @param {integer} height
  \*/
  function createScatterPlotMatrix(width, height) {

  const margin = { top: 10, left: 30, bottom: 30, right: 10 };

  const grid_height = height / numerics.length;
  const grid_width = width / numerics.length;
  const fontSize = 25;

  const svg = parent.append("svg")
  .attr("viewBox", \[0, 0, width, height\]);

  const scatterplot_matrix = svg.selectAll("g.scatterplot")
  .data(d3.cross(numerics, numerics))
  .join("g")
  .attr("transform", (d, i) =\> "translate(" + (i % numerics.length) \* grid_width + "," + Math.floor(i / numerics.length) \* grid_height + ")");

  scatterplot_matrix.each(function (d) { // each pair from cross combination
  const g = d3.select(this);

       // label the same attribute axis
       if (d[0] == d[1]) {
           const labelXPosition = grid_width/ 2;
           const labelYPosition = grid_height/2;
      
           g.append("text")
               .text(d[0])
               .attr("transform", "translate(" + labelXPosition + "," + labelYPosition + ")")
               .style("text-anchor", "middle")
               .style("fill", "black")
               .style("font-size", fontSize);
      
       } else {
           scatterPlot(d[0], d[1], g, grid_width, grid_height, margin);
       }

  })
  }

/\*\*

* @param {string} attributeX

* @param {string} attributeY

* @param {nodeElement} scatterplotCell

* @param {integer} width

* @param {integer} height

* @param {Object} margin
  \*/
  function scatterPlot(attributeX, attributeY, scatterplotCell, width, height, margin) {
  // Filter data to remove points with missing values
  const filteredData = df1.filter(d =\> d\[attributeX\] != null && d\[attributeY\] != null);

  // Get the extent (min and max values) for each attribute
  const extentX = d3.extent(filteredData, d =\> d\[attributeX\]);
  const extentY = d3.extent(filteredData, d =\> d\[attributeY\]);

  // Set the input domain of the scales to the extent of the data
  const x_scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain(extentX).range(\[margin.left, width - margin.right\]);
  const y_scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain(extentY).range(\[height - margin.bottom, margin.top\]);

  // Create axes
  const axisX = d3.axisBottom(x_scale).ticks(4);
  scatterplotCell
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height - margin.bottom})`)
  .call(axisX);

  const axisY = d3.axisLeft(y_scale).ticks(4);
  scatterplotCell
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, 0)`)
  .call(axisY);

  // drawing the points of the scatterplot
  scatterplotCell.selectAll("circle")
  .data(filteredData)
  .join("circle")
  .attr("cx", d =\> x_scale(d\[attributeX\]))
  .attr("cy", d =\> y_scale(d\[attributeY\]))
  .attr("r", 3)  // Set the radius of the points
  .attr("fill", d =\> color_scale(d\[categorical\]));  // Color the points according to the color scheme
  }

/\*\*

* @param {integer} width
* @param {integer} height
  \*/

function createHorizontalParallelCoordinates(width, height) {
const margin = { top: 10, left: 30, bottom: 30, right: 10 };

    const svg = parent.append("svg")
        .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height]);
    
    // Define the dimensions of the plot area
    const plotWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right;
    const plotHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
    // Define the attributes to be plotted
    const attributes = ["bill_length_mm", "bill_depth_mm", "flipper_length_mm", "body_mass_g"];
    
    // Filter out rows with missing data
    const filteredData = df1.filter(d => !attributes.some(attr => d[attr] == null));
    
    // Define a scale for each attribute
    const scales = new Map(attributes.map(attr => [
        attr,
        d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain(d3.extent(filteredData, d => d[attr]))
            .range([margin.left, plotWidth + margin.left])
    ]));
    
    // defining a line generator
    const line = d3.line()
        .x((d, i) => scales.get(attributes[i])(d))
        .y((_, i) => i * plotHeight / (attributes.length - 1) + margin.top);
    
    // drawing the lines
    svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(filteredData)
        .join("path")
        .attr("d", d => line(attributes.map(attr => d[attr])))
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", d => color_scale(d["species"]))
        .attr("stroke-width", 1.5);
    
    // drawing the axes
    attributes.forEach((attr, i) => {
        const y = i * plotHeight / (attributes.length - 1) + margin.top;
    
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", `translate(0,${y})`)
            .call(d3.axisTop(scales.get(attr)));
    
        svg.append("text")
            .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left - 10},${y})`)
            .attr("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("dominant-baseline", "middle")
            .text(attr);
    });

}


JSON file:
{

"name": "a2",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index_edited.js",
"type": "module",
"scripts": {
"test": "echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1",
"start": "snowpack dev"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"d3": "^7.9.0",
"snowpack": "^3.8.8",
"zero-md": "^2.5.4"
}
}

CSS file:
body {
font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
font-size: 1.2rem;
font-weight: 400;
}

main {
max-width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

a {
color: #512da8;
text-decoration: none;
}

#codearea {
font-family: monospace;
}

a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}

a:visited {
color: #311b92;
}

h1 {
font-size: 3rem;
font-weight: 400;
margin: 3rem 0 1rem 0;
}

h2 {
font-size: 2.5rem;
font-weight: 400;
margin: 2rem 0 1rem 0;
}

h3 {
font-size: 2rem;
font-weight: 400;
margin: 1rem 0 1rem 0;
}

table {
width: 100%;
border: none;
}

th,
td {
border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
padding: 0 5px;
}

th {
text-align: left;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: 500;
}

td\>span {
padding: 1px 5px;
margin: 0px 10px;
}

span.tag {
display: inline;
padding: 6px 10px;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: black;
color: white;
justify-content: center;
}

code {
font-family: monospace;
font-size: 1.1rem;
background-color: #b0bec5;
color: black;
border-radius: 4px;
padding: 0.1rem 0.2rem;
}

div.task {
padding: 0.1rem 1.2rem;
margin: 2rem 0;
border-radius: 6px;
background-color: #cfd8dc;
}

div.optional {
padding: 0.1rem 1.2rem;
margin: 2rem 0;
border-radius: 6px;
background-color: rgb(212, 200, 254);
}

span.monospace {
font-family: monospace;
}

.responsive {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

I wanted to run the program on my browser to take a look at the scatterplot and parallel line charts but my code keep running into issues. I tried changing the syntax, added filter functions because the dataset has missing data items even tried altering the actual dataset. I created a HTML file uses <script type="module"> and also tried to serve my file locally on a python server but I could not find my file on the local server but none of that has worked as my code is still stuck at debugging on the first line. I would really appreciate someone's insight.

Welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider providing a minimal reproducible example on CodeSandbox, StackBlitz or so, which will help a lot
